# How to get the best combination of numbers from the array of numbers that are closest to the number x

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get the best combination of numbers from the array `numbers` that are closest to the number `max`.
(addition numbers from array `numbers` is allowed)

```
var numbers = [2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 20, 54, 89, 10]; // some numbers in array
var max = 10; // the highest possible number we want to get from array
var highest = [];
```

In this case, the output should be (3, 7) or (2, 5, 3) or (10), the output should not be 9

I have done this, but this is not what I want.

```
var possibles = numbers.filter(number => number <= max);
highest.push(Math.max(...possibles));
possibles.sort((a,b) => b - a);
possibles.forEach(number =>{
  if( (max - highest[0]) <= number){
     highest.push(Math.max(...possibles));
  }
});
```

The output in this case is 9, which is not the highest possible number.

Comment: Please also mention on what you've tried so far

Comment: [You can check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Comment: why do not want `[10]` as result as well?

Comment: I do, I forgot to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by using some methods to minimize the data and the iteration.

First of all it take a variable to keep an actual minimum sum of all values of a temporary array `right`.

Another function checks if an array with same value already exists in the result array.

At the end `iter` performs some checks for exit or adding `right` to `result` and finally fork the call to itself by using either the actual value or not.

The result set contains all possible results with the max possible sum.

```js
function getMax(values, max) {
    const
        includes = (arrays, array) => arrays.some(a => a.join() === array.join()),
        iter = ([value, ...left], right = [], sum = 0) => {
            ++count;
            if (sum > max) return;
            if (sum > min) {
                result = [right];
                min = sum;
            } else if (sum === min && !includes(result, right)) {
                result.push(right);
            }
            if (sum === max || value === undefined) return;

            iter(left, [...right, value], sum + value);
            iter(left, [...right], sum);
        };

    let min = 0,
        count = 0,
        result = [];

    iter(values.filter(v => v <= max).sort((a, b) => b - a));
    console.log('iterations', count);
    return result;
}

getMax([2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 20, 54, 89, 10], 10).map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot, but I have a question. In the case I needed to return only 1 highest possible combination of these numbers (I need to make it faster), what should I change ?

Comment: you still need to iterate until the end, because you do not know in advance which combination gets the maximum.

Comment: Ah, okay. So there's probably not any faster way right ?

Comment: i added soem changes and now `10` is a valid result as well until you want at lest two items in the result array. by sorting descending, the iteration count is the smalest. cou could play with sorting and have a look to count.